# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Variabel1.(requiered integer)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm a newbie in CodeIgniter and now I'm learning from a book to make a simple calculator.

I got a problem when im running the multiplication process, I'm getting the following error and guess the problem is on the controller

**Code:**

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent ::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("hello"); 
}
public function perkalian() 
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('v1','Variabel 1','requiered 
    integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('v2','Variabel 2','requiered 
    integer');
if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        $data['v1'] = (int)$this->input->post('v1',true); 
        $data['v2'] = (int)$this->input->post('v2',true); 
        $data['hasil']=$data['v1']*$data['v2']; 
    }
else
    {
        $data['v1']=0;
        $data['v2']=0;
        $data['hasil']=0; }

$data['v1'] = (int)$this->input->post('v1',true);
$data['v2'] = (int)$this->input->post('v2',true);
$data['hasil']=$data['v1']*$data['v2'];
}
else
{
$data['v1']=0;
$data['v2']=0;
$data['hasil']=0;
}
$this->load->view('perkalian',$data);
}
public function pertambahan()
{
$data['v1'] = (int)$this->input->post('v1',true);
$data['v2'] = (int)$this->input->post('v2',true);
$data['hasil']=$data['v1']+$data['v2'];;
$this->load->view('pertambahan',$data);
}
```

Comment: We need more code to be able to help you.

Comment: What's that `library yg sudah disediakan CI` part? Is the a valid php syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your validation rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('v1','Variabel 1','requiered integer');
```

should be

```
// required instead of requiered and you forgot |
$this->form_validation->set_rules('v1','Variabel 1','required|integer');
```

Also do the same thing in the other set_rules function

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try This Code:**

```
public function perkalian() 
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('v1','Variabel 1','required|integer');//changes
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('v2','Variabel 2','required|integer');//changes

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) //changes
    {
        if (validation_errors()) {//changes
            $data['error'] = validation_errors();//changes
        } else {//changes
            $data['error'] = '';//changes
        }

        $data['v1']= 0;
        $data['v2']= 0;
        $data['hasil']= 0;      

    }else{
        $data['v1'] = (int)$this->input->post('v1',true); 
        $data['v2'] = (int)$this->input->post('v2',true); 
        $data['hasil']=$data['v1']*$data['v2'];
        $data['error'] = '';//changes
    }
    echo'<pre>';print_r($data);die;//changes
    $this->load->view('perkalian',$data);
}
```